# evaluate the information related to combined columns in R using hash or other methods

Tags: r, algorithm

I have a record table, which looks like as follows

```
ab   cd   ef   10
ac   bd   fg   20
abc  cde  efg  10
ab   cd   ef   20
```

In the above table, the first three columns in the first row and the fourth row are exactly the same. I need to combine these two rows together, to get

```
ab cd ef 30
```

What should be the right approach to achieve this in R. Iterative every row and column can do the job, but it is too slow. I think we need something like hashing the first three columns together, but I do not know how to do it in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following with the package `dplyr`

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(header= FALSE, text = "
ab   cd   ef   10
ac   bd   fg   20
abc  cde  efg  10
ab   cd   ef   20")
```

**Code**

```
  library(dplyr)
  group_by(df, V1, V2, V3) %>%
      mutate(SUM = sum(V4)) %>%
      distinct()
  ## Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
  ## Groups: V1, V2, V3
  ## 
  ##    V1  V2  V3 V4 SUM
  ## 1  ab  cd  ef 10  30
  ## 2  ac  bd  fg 20  20
  ## 3 abc cde efg 10  10
```

Answer (score 1):

And this is an one-line alternative using base R and the function `aggregate`:

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(header= FALSE, text = "
ab   cd   ef   10
ac   bd   fg   20
abc  cde  efg  10
ab   cd   ef   20")
```

**Solution**

```
> aggregate(V4 ~ ., data=df, sum)
   V1  V2  V3 V4
1  ab  cd  ef 30
2 abc cde efg 10
3  ac  bd  fg 20
```

`V4` represents the column you will sum, after grouping your data by `.` (all the rest of the columns).